# push cloned <option> into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

The Code as follows

```
var options = $("#select> option").clone();

$('#btn').on('click',function(e){
 
       e.preventDefault();
       var copyEl = [];
       copyEl.push("<select id='select"+i+"'class='select form-control'>");
       options.each(function(){
                console.log(this);
                copyEl.push(this);
            });
       
      copyEl.push("</select>");

      copyEl = $(copyEl.join(''));

      $('#div').after(copyEl.clone());

});
```

> this is what i do find when inspect the element
>
> [object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement][object HTMLOptionElement]

the console print

```
<option id='1'>Toy</option>
<option id='2'>Story</option>
```

which is result that i do need to push in the array , this code was working fine with the `<datalist>` but is not working with `<select>` any way to add the 
to the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want create select dynamically using cloned options. Use [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) to create selected then [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) cloned options to select.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var select = $("<select>", { id : 'select' + i,
         'class': 'select form-control'
    }); 
    select.append(options);
    $('#div').after(select);
});
```

---

As per comment, use `outerHTML` property

```
options.each(function(){
    copyEl.push(this.outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: yes but i have to commit to the array option its a full form copied in the run time multiple times i just make a sample of the code its too big and this is its only problem

Comment: @user3191664, ok then you should learn to create HTML using jQuery. However you try with `copyEl.push(this.outerHTML);` instead of `copyEl.push(this);`

Comment: any idea or reference to repair the duplication problem

Comment: @user3191664, Mate you need to debug it

Comment: Never mind :) i already did but it still print it duplicate but printing is better than not :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

`options = document.getElementById("selectID").outerHTML;
 copyEL.push(options);`

This will include the HTML for the `select` menu, so you don't need to append that. It will also include the options, with HTML.